# Python IndexError: List index out of range (sweep algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, loops, while-loop

There's a problem with my code where it shows the error:

```
File "C:\Users\gileu\Google Drive\FIME\Temas Selectos de Optimización\Heuristica de Barridos\Barridos.py", line 85, in <module>
        elif(datos[j][2] <= ca):
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried manually displaying the values that I'm supposed to compare and it works, but when it is used in the `if` statement, it crashes.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
from math import *
'''Inicialización: Obetener los datos necesarios para la funcionalidad del programa.
El formato del dato individual debe ser transformado al siguiente formato:
dato[i] = [x,y,d] donde:
x = coordenada x del dato
y = coordenada y del dato
d = demanda a atender del dato '''
datos = [[0,1,33],[1,0,15],[-1,1,10],[-1,-1,10],[1,1,20],[0,-1,17],[1,-1,13],[-1,0,9]]

#El origen pertenecerá a todos los grupos creados, y se tomará como el origen. 
Or = [0,0]

#La capacidad de cada grupo debe ser mayor que el máximo de todas las demandas, esto para poder antende las necesidades de todos los datos.
c = 80

ang = []
angO = []
grupos = []

print("Paso 1: Conseguir los grados de cada punto.")
print()

for i in range(len(datos)):
    #Cuadrante II:
    if(datos[i][0] < 0 and datos[i][1] > 0):
        ang.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0]))+180)
        angO.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0]))+180)
    #Cuadrante III:
    elif(datos[i][0] < 0 and datos[i][1] < 0):
        ang.append(270-degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0])))
        angO.append(270-degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0])))
    #Cuadrante IV:
    elif(datos[i][0] > 0 and datos[i][1] < 0):
        ang.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0]))+360)
        angO.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0]))+360)
    #Eje Y:
    elif(datos[i][0] == 0 and datos[i][1] > 0):
        ang.append(90)
        angO.append(90)
    #Eje -X:
    elif(datos[i][0] < 0 and datos[i][1] == 0):
        ang.append(180)
        angO.append(180)
    #Eje -Y:
    elif(datos[i][0] == 0 and datos[i][1] < 0):
        ang.append(270)
        angO.append(270)
    #Eje X:
    elif(datos[i][0] > 0 and datos[i][1] == 0 or datos[i][0] == 0 and datos[i][1] == 0):
        ang.append(0)
        angO.append(0)
    #Para cualquier otro ángulo:
    else:
        ang.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0])))
        angO.append(degrees(atan(datos[i][1]/datos[i][0])))

print("Paso 2: Ordenar los ángulos de menor a mayor.")
print()
angO.sort()

print("Coordenadas en posicion original: ", ang)
print("Coordenadas en posicion ordenada: ", angO)

print()
print("Paso 3: Proceso de asignación.")
print()

i = 0
j = 0
while(angO):
    grupos.append([])
    print(grupos[i])
    ca = c
    print("Capacidad Actual: ", ca)
    print("Numeros por asignar: ", angO)
    print("Grupo actual: ", i)
    print("Numero actual: ", j)
    print(datos[j][2])
    print(ang.index(angO[0]))
    while(ca>=0):
        if(ca == 0):
            i = i + 1
            break
        elif(datos[j][2] <= ca):
            grupos[i].append(ang.index(angO[0]))
            angO.remove(angO[0])
            j = j + 1
        elif(datos[j][2] > ca):
            i = i + 1
            break

for i in range(len(grupos)):
    print("Grupo ", i, ": ", grupos[i])
```

Comment: Welcome, Gilberto, it would be great to post the complete error-trace, including the source code location. Would you mind to kindly update your post so as to meet this standard practice?

Comment: @user3666197 I have updated the post. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in this part of code:

```
while(ca>=0):
    if(ca == 0):
        i = i + 1
        break
    elif(datos[j][2] <= ca):
        grupos[i].append(ang.index(angO[0]))
        angO.remove(angO[0])
        j = j + 1
    elif(datos[j][2] > ca):
        i = i + 1
        break
```

You have initialized `ca=c`, which is 80. In this while loop, you are never decreasing `ca`, so this is essentially an infinite loop. While the value `len(datos)` is finite, if for all values of `j`, `datos[j][2] <= ca` is met, `j` will exceed length of `datos` at some point, which will then give this `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

You need to put a condition for `j` here.

Comment: I forgot about decreasing `ca`! let me see if that fixes the code.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up validating this way: 
`if(j < len(angO)): j = j + 1`

Comment: Yes, I thought so...there must be some condition on `j` for it being less than `len(datos)` or `len(ang0)`, whatever suits.